# LINQ to create a calculated value based on the value of two other columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Simplified scenario:

I want to create a calculated string property based on the value of two properties, Field1 and Field2. When Field1 has a value, Field2 is null, and viceversa. They can't be both null.

Let's call the calculated value "cv". The rule is: If Field1 is null, cv = Field2, and if Field2 is null, cv = Field1.

How can I achieve this using LINQ to Entities?

thanks.

Comment: Did you tried like cv = Field2 ?? Field1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will something like this work for you?

```
 context.People.Select(p => new {cv = p.DisplayName ?? p.RealName});
```